# Restore deleted file with history in git

Tags: git, github

How to restore an accidentally deleted file and folder in git after push. Below is the scenario.

1. Accidentally deleted a folder which has a single file and made a bunch of changes to other files.
2. Now, pushed all these changes. So this push has the deleted folder along with other changed files.
3. On top of this, there were a few more pushes.

Now, can I restore the deleted file, along with history and then push back to repo.

Comment: Git doesn't *have* "file history". Git has *commit history*. Restore the file(s) and your history says "commit K deleted some files, later commit R produced new files with the same name and the same contents as before." That's as close as you get. Use Ryan's answer below to get the file(s) back.

Comment: If you didn't use git to remove them you could reset your workspace to get them back. Are you sure they are deleted?

Comment: @osowskit what do you mean by "if you did not use git to remove" . My question itself is "how to restore if I deleted the file and pushed the deleted file?"

Comment: Thx. I'd recommend including the git commands you used to clarify that this wasn't deleting on the client-side only. I'd revert the commit to avoid rewriting history.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just check it out from a commit where it existed. If the commit that deleted the file is the tip of whatever you have currently checked out, that’s `HEAD^` (the commit before last):

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- path/to/file
```

Then you can commit and push it.

Comment: You can replace HEAD^ with a commit SHA and that will also work.

Comment: I tried that but it does not restore the history for me.

Comment: @waynix: You need to pick a commit where the file exists. It’s not always going to be `HEAD^`.

Comment: @Ry-: I did get the file back, but the history was lost. But when I execute git blame on the file I only get my name and not the name of the original committer.

Comment: @waynix: Oh, sorry, misread that. Is the history there if you use `git log` instead of `git blame` on the file? (Or did you checkout from a commit in a separate timeline of sorts?)

Comment: What is the latest word on this? Was history maintained? Does `git log` show the history of the restored file before the deletion?

Comment: This did not preserve history for me; I see only the latest commit in the file's history. FWIW I checked out using the commit hash.

Comment: This did not retain the history for me.

Comment: @GarretWilson See MadHatter's response, which retains history and is short and elegant.

Answer (score 21):

It is possible, with help of [Git copy file preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937359/git-copy-file-preserving-history) you need to copy the file before it was deleted.

I will write here a complete example. First I will prepare some test repository:

```
git init
echo "test content" > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m "start"
echo "test content 2" >> file.txt
git commit -am "next commit"
rm file.txt
git commit -am "Delete file, lose history"
```

Now we have a test repository without the file. To restore the file with its commit history the process is following: create a branch where the file did exist. Then make two copies of this file, each with history. Then merge back to master and only one of the two copies will get deleted during the merge.
Be sure to use your commit hash instead of `190112b` in example below.

```
git checkout 190112b -b before-deletion
git mv file.txt file1.txt
git commit -m "Move file (1)"
SAVED=`git rev-parse HEAD`
git reset --hard "HEAD^"
git mv file.txt file2.txt
git commit -m "Move file (2)"
git merge $SAVED
git commit -a -n
```

OK, so now in this branch we have two copies of this file. Each copy preserves history. Now when we merge this back into master, one file will disappear (or will have wrong history), the other one will keep the history.

```
git checkout master
git merge before-deletion
git commit -a -n
git rm file1.txt
git mv file2.txt file.txt
git commit -m "recovery finished"
```

And that's it.

Comment: Worked. Restored the file with its history. Thanks!

Comment: @RodrigoElias great to hear! :)

Comment: I followed your steps above, but had errors with `git merge`.  When I ignored the errors and carried on with the next command, it all just worked.  Amazing!

Comment: Was it line `git commit -m "next commit"` ? I will remove it, it's unnecessary, the next command fixes it.

Comment: It was in a few places:the second block `git merge $SAVED`. I got a `CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "file.txt"->"file2.txt" in branch "HEAD" rename "file.txt"->"file1.txt" in " ...`. I used git 2.7.4

Comment: Worked as a charm. I just ignored the warning. hanks!

Comment: Can you add comments before each git command? I don't know what is specific of this example and what should be changed. For example, what if the commit that deleted the file is not the one before HEAD?

Comment: After trying many different methods. Finally this solution worked to restored directly with history intact. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 8):

Just encountered a similar scenario: A file was previously deleted, now I need to restore it.

Step 1: Locate the commit which deletes the file (say the file name is test.log):

```
$ git log --all --stat --diff-filter=D -- test.log
commit aec72339081df3bc621a6c0cd3687257778466e4
(Author, Date, commit message etc appear here)
```

Step 2: Restore the file from that commit (aec723390 from above), note the `^` for the prior commit containing the not-yet-deleted file:

```
$ git restore --source aec723390^ -- test.log
```

Step 3: The file will be restored to your working tree (but not the repo until you actually commit it), you may add it via `git add test.log` then make a commit:

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    test.log

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$
```

Comment: Is this any different than simply recreating the exact file manually? According to this description, after `git restore` the file is still untracked, presumably the same as if I would have copied the file to the directory from a backup, for example. Where does the extra history tracking come in? Does `git restore` provide something extra to history tracking that my simply recreating the file from scratch would not?

Comment: @GarretWilson I do not quite understand what you meant by "my simply recreating the file from scratch". The scenario in my case is, I'm pretty sure there is such a file in my git repository a long time ago, and the file may gets deleted by a commit made by someone else. I cannot simply recreate the file since I'm not fully sure what is in the file.

Comment: @GarretWilson That's why I have to get the file from git commit history.

Comment: @MadHatter Simply restoring a file is not a rocket science. The tricky part is when you want this file to be tracked like it was never gone (i.e. with `git blame` showing all the authors of each line) - this is what the topic starter asked. Your solution does not achieve this, unfortunately.

Comment: @JBM `git blame`: git-blame - Show what revision and author last modified each line of a file. For this topic, I thought we were actually talking about restoring a deleted file in git.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're currently on the master branch, an easy solution is to find the GIT SHA1 from the last commit (using something like gitk helps) with the deleted file you want.

Run the command

```
git checkout <GIT SHA1 value>
```

Copy the contents of the file into notepad (or any text editor)

Run the command

```
git checkout master
```

Recreate the file with the contents from notepad

Comment: Will this bring back the history of the file also?

Comment: Yes it should, assuming the file is in the same location with the same name