# See history of a restored file from before delete in Git

Tags: git

I have a file `foo.bar` with a long and interesting history over years. It has been modified. It has been renamed. With the right `git log` parameters, I can still trace its modification history. This is important to me.

In revision `33333` I delete `foo.bar` because it seemed like we needed that feature. But four commits later, in revision `77777`, it turns out we need that feature, so I wanted `foo.bar` back.

As most everyone knows I can issue:

```
git checkout 3333 -- path/to/foo.bar
```

But nobody seems to know definitively whether I'll still see the full history that I would see before when issuing `git log`, in revisions `88888` and beyond.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42287548/421049 for example claims to answer this exact same question. **But that answer is unclear as to whether the history before and after delete will be connected in the log, and questions in the comments for clarification have gone unanswered.**

Comment: IMO you worry too much. You need the old file and its code so you just checkout it and the rest is history, pun intended. Why care at all if `git log` connects or not the history of the file?

Answer (score 3):

The way to find out is to try it.

If you *do* try it, you'll find that `git log -- file` (with or without `--follow`) does indeed keep looking.

Note:

> With the right `git log` parameters, I can still trace [a particular file's] modification history ...

It's important to remember here that Git doesn't store *file* history.  Git stores *commits*, and the commits—and their graph—*are* the history.

When you run `git log -- file` or `git log --follow -- file`, Git *synthesizes* a file history, by showing you some selected subset of the *actual* history.  The actual history is, of course, just *every commit starting at some ending point and working backwards, following all parents of merges unless `--first-parent` is used to follow only the first parents of merges*.

The *synthetic, limited history* produced by omitting some commits and showing other commits will, of course, depend on which commits are shown and which commits are omitted.  Here, it becomes important to distingiush between two separate processes:

- How does Git decide which commits to traverse?
- Having traversed those commits, how does Git decide which commits to *show?*

The unlimited, default `git log` action is to traverse *all [reachable](http://think-like-a-git.net/) commits* and to show *all commits traversed*, which makes the two questions synonymous.  You just need to understand the idea of *reachability*, which is why I provided the link to [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) here.  But as soon as you enable what [the `git log` documentation calls History Simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification), the two become separate.  The documentation uses what I think is poor phrasing here:

> > one part is selecting the commits and the other is how to do it

What they mean here is:

- *one part is selecting the commits **to be shown*** (added words mine, emphasis mine): This is my second bullet point above.  After, or during, the traversal of some subset of commits reachable from the starting point, we show some *subset* of *those* commits.
- *the other is how to do [the traversal]:* "it" is a particularly useless pronoun here, referring to the general idea of history simplification.  This amounts to saying *the method used to do history simplification is the method used to do history simplification*, which, well ... okay then!

In any case, the main idea—which applies to everything except the `--ancestry-path` option—is to start with a concept they call TREESAME here.  To apply the idea, we must also look at each commit's parent or parents.

We already know, of course, that to do any kind of commit-graph walk, we have Git grab a commit out of the object database and examine it and gather up its parent hash IDs.  Most commits have just one parent, so it's obvious where to move next.  A few commits—there is at least one—are *root* commits, which is defined as a commit with *no* parents, and it's obvious what to do here as well: just stop traversing.  The remaining commits, neither root nor ordinary, are *merge* commits, and by default, without history simplification, Git would look at *all* parents of each merge commit.

When history simplification is turned on, though, Git *doesn't* look at all parents.  Instead, it uses this TREESAME idea.  To decide if commits C (child) and P<sub>i</sub> (the i'th parent) are TREESAME, Git compares the contents of all the files that we're interested in, in that commit—and now the `--follow` and/or `-- path` part matters, because this declares *which files we find interesting right now*.  So Git pretends that commits C and P<sub>i</sub> have *only those files in them*, and says: *are the files identical, or different?*

If the files are different, the two commits are not TREESAME.  If the files have the same contents, the two commits are TREESAME.

Git will select commit C to be *shown* if it is not-TREESAME to *any* parent, i.e., if the file(s) in C, after any stripping-out, differ from those in any P<sub>i</sub>.  But if the commit is a merge commit—has more than one parent—the parent it will *follow*, by default, to find more commits to maybe-show maybe-follow, is one of the parents that *is* TREESAME to C.

There are a handful of options (five total, including the default) to change the way the commit-following works.  One of them, `--sparse`, also changes the set of commits to be shown, otherwise this "not-TREESAME-to-any-parent" rule is the rule used for showing traversed commits.

Last, we can look at `--follow` itself.  What this does is simple—probably *too* simple, since it fails with `--full-history`, for instance.  As with any `git log -- paths` operation, it turns on history simplification, so that only commits that "touch" the given path get displayed.  However, it also enables Git's *rename detection*, and simultaneously, demands that only one *path* be specified.

As Git traverses commits from child to parent, doing the simplification steps to determine (a) which parent(s) to follow and (b) which commits to display, Git also checks for a case where the diff, from parent-to-child, says that the file at *path* in the child is the result of a rename from a different path in the parent.  If that's the case, then as soon as Git switches from examining commit C to examining parent commit P, it *also* switches *which path name it is using for history simplification*.  Now instead of `path/to/file.ext` it might be looking for `old/path/to/file.txt`, for instance.

If you have commits in your commit graph in which there is *no* copy of some file under some path such as `path/to/file.ext`, `git log` still traverses those commits.  It's just that those commits obviously don't *change* that file—they don't even have that file—and therefore each child commit is TREESAME to each of its parent commits.  At some point during this traversal, if a commit appears in which `path/to/file.ext` *is* in a parent and not in the child, the traversal may—or may not, depending on your chosen history simplification—move to that parent.  If the file is added or removed in an ordinary, single-parent commit, the behavior is easy to understand, as there's no special TREESAME weirdness to apply.  If the file is added or removed in a commit C that is a merge and has multiple parents P<sub>1</sub>…P<sub>n</sub>, the TREESAME rules will, by default, take Git down a commit-graph path that *doesn't* have the file!

To really figure this all out, study [the git log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).  The answers are in it—once you can get past the not-so-good phrasing, anyway.

#### Side note: `git blame` is different

Both `git log` and `git blame` will walk the commit graph, but `git blame` (or its less-charged synonym, `git annotate`) has rather different algorithms in it for deciding which file(s) to look at in which commit(s).  Its goal is to locate which recent commit changed any given line of any given file.  When you hit a point at which a file does not exist in the parent commit but does exist in the child, *every line is added* and so the tree-walking stops at this point.

To continue before this point, it's necessary to find some earlier commit that does have the file—which is easy-ish to do using `git log`, history simplification, and the parent that *doesn't* have the commit as the starting point.  You can then start the `git blame` operation at the point where the file existed, and work backwards from there.

Comment: _"and their graph—are the history"_ this sounds better, as the collection of graph and commits is plural.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: The em-dash is almost an appositive, in which case the verb should agree (number-wise) with the word before the appositive phrase, but I can't find a proper authoritative citation here. I think I will go with plural though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the history is kept.

The question in the comment was about `git blame foo.bar`, not about `git log foo.bar`