# Can Plastic SCM track code moved between files?

Tags: plasticscm

It seems that Plastic SCM does not track code moved between files (compare with e.g. [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728922/how-does-git-track-source-code-moved-between-files)) Am I right, or is there a way how to switch this feature on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I work for Plastic SCM).

As far as I know git is able to track moved fragments of code between files when you run a "git blame", but it doesn't use this information during merge, correct? Git is able to calculate the "moved fragment" between files if it happens on the same commit and that's what it does while processing the 'blame'.

No, Plastic is not able to do that yet, which is a shame because we're already doing some interesting things around the idea:

- First we have [**semantic method history**](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2013/10/new-semantic-methodhist-is-now-out.html) which is able to track the history of a given method even when it has been moved, renamed and modified, but always inside the same file. We have plans to extend this to a repository wide basis, indeed we were about to implement it by the end of last year but we had to postpone it since we got some other highly requested features to work on.
- The 'semantic method history' is based on the [**SemanticMerge**](http://www.semanticmerge.com/) tech we've developed. Right now it also works inside the file, but plans are also to come up with SemanticMerge multi-file (we even have a working prototype already). I expect this to be several steps ahead of what other tools can do.
- Applying the last two together it wouldn't be hard to do something like 'blame with moved code', which as you pointed is something really great to have. Hopefully we'll release something like this in the coming months.